# What function invoke when swip the UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a UITableView and stetted it editable .and I want to know which function was invoked when I swiped on the cell .because I would like to do some stuff before the delete button appear.

Answer (score 2):

`tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` this method is called as per my knowledge

Comment: @VIRGIL if this correctly answers your question, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of Aalok's answer.